# Does Google Chrome store/cache usernames and passwords even when you tell it to "never save" your username and password?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

Does Google **Chrome** store/cache usernames and passwords even when you tell it to "**never save**" your username and password?

I'm trying to recover a username and password from years ago and I think I told it to "**never save**" my password so I don't know what to do.

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't. That said, most sites give you hints in what your username and password are. For example, they have options: I forgot my username, or I forgot my password, which usually allows you to retrieve them through email. If there's only I forgot password, you can try that. It will likely ask you for your email address. Guess a few and see if one works.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no.  If you told it to never save, it will not keep that information.  Which makes sense, as if it did, this would me a massive violation of security and trust.

I am a strong supporter for password managers like [LastPass](https://www.lastpass.com/), [KeePass](https://keepass.info/), or other similar products.  These password managers are portable, easy to use, and secure.

Comment: I can no longer suggest LastPass due to it's extremely poor iOS and Android support.  I am a big fan of [1Password](https://www.1password.com/)

Comment: @Keltari So even a high up at Google cant view something where a user said "Never Save"?

Comment: @Ramhound I havent used it on iOS in many years, but I have been using it on Android for years now, with no issues.  What poor support are you referring to?

Comment: @PaulMcBurney What are you asking?  Are you asking if Google secretly stores all your usernames and passwords without your permission?

Comment: @Keltari - At some point in 2019 LastPass change the way Credit Cards and Addresses worked.  You can no longer select those "cards" on any website (at least on iOS).  LastPass suppose doesn't answer your question when you asked if the feature will return.  This makes filling out payment information difficult.  I have found 1Password works no matter what (with bonus functionality within applications (i.e. Bank Of America, Chase, ect).

Answer (score 0):

No. That is the point of that setting. So if it was not saved (you so say) then set up whatever user name and password you might need.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's a security issue. If you say no you want it to mean no

If you know the email account that you used, you can try the password reset on the website. Choose the 'I forgot my account name' or similar

Answer (score 0):

I might be on thin ice, but yes Chrome has to store something.
As the option **never save** implies, Chrome has to memorize the site and username to never save the username/password combination for this site. Otherwise it would just be a **not now** option.
Besides this hypothetical view on your problem, I would hope it does **not** save the password along with other required information when you ask it not to do so and therefor you should be out of luck.